# Ejercicio de cadenas en Java

Tags: java, bucles, string

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio que dice:

> Hacer un algoritmo que pida cadenas separadas por _  y muestre la suma
>   impar y la suma par de cada cadena, terminar cuando se ingrese la
>   cadena PARAR, y mostrar el total de las sumas impares y el total de
>   las pares.

Hice el código de abajo pero me marca error al momento de ingresar parar. Ayuda :(

```
    do {    
        System.out.println("Ingrese una cadena:");
        cad1=leer.nextLine();

        cad2=cad1.concat(ayuda);

        for(i=0,sumapar=0,sumaimpar=0;i<cad2.length();i++){
            if(cad2.charAt(i)=='-'||cad2.charAt(i)=='0'||cad2.charAt(i)=='1'||cad2.charAt(i)=='2'||cad2.charAt(i)=='3'||cad2.charAt(i)=='4'||cad2.charAt(i)=='5'||cad2.charAt(i)=='6'||cad2.charAt(i)=='7'||cad2.charAt(i)=='8'||cad2.charAt(i)=='9'){
                num+=cad1.charAt(i);
            }else{
                int n=Integer.parseInt(num);
                num="";
                if(n%2==0){
                    sumapar+=n;
                    sumapartotal+=sumapar;
                }else{
                    sumaimpar+=n;
                    sumaimpartotal+=sumaimpar;
                }
            }

    }System.out.println("La suma total de pares es: "+sumapar+ " y la suma total de los impares es: " +sumaimpar);

}while(cad1!=cadf);

    System.out.println("La suma total par es: "+sumapartotal+ " y la suma total impar es " +sumaimpartotal);

}
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que error te da? en que momento?

Comment: deberías chequear que la cadena sea 'PARAR'

Answer (score 0):

Supongo, por que no lo tienes en el código, que tu variable `cadf` la tendras declarada e inicializada de la siguiente manera: `String cadf = "PARAR"`.

En cualquier caso, para comparar cadenas en Java se utiliza el método [equals()](http://www.w3api.com/wiki/Java:String.equals())

```
}while(cad1.equals(cadf));
```

Para no tener problemas a la hora de escribir `"parar"` en mayúsculas o minúsculas, utilizaremos [equalsIgnoreCase()](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/string/string_equalsignorecase.php)

Tu ejemplo completo quedaría así:

```
  do {    
        System.out.println("Ingrese una cadena:");
        cad1=leer.nextLine();

        cad2=cad1.concat(ayuda);

        for(i=0,sumapar=0,sumaimpar=0;i<cad2.length();i++){
            if(cad2.charAt(i)=='-'||cad2.charAt(i)=='0'||cad2.charAt(i)=='1'||cad2.charAt(i)=='2'||cad2.charAt(i)=='3'||cad2.charAt(i)=='4'||cad2.charAt(i)=='5'||cad2.charAt(i)=='6'||cad2.charAt(i)=='7'||cad2.charAt(i)=='8'||cad2.charAt(i)=='9'){
                num+=cad1.charAt(i);
            }else{
                int n=Integer.parseInt(num);
                num="";
                if(n%2==0){
                    sumapar+=n;
                    sumapartotal+=sumapar;
                }else{
                    sumaimpar+=n;
                    sumaimpartotal+=sumaimpar;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("La suma total de pares es: "+sumapar+ " y la suma total de los impares es: " +sumaimpar);

    }while(cad1.equalsIgnoreCase(cadf));

    System.out.println("La suma total par es: "+sumapartotal+ " y la suma total impar es " +sumaimpartotal);

   }
}
```